# Python Flet scroll mode for Datatable

Tags: python, pandas, datatable, scroll, flet

I am working on a project using flet Datatable that aims to display the pandas table which has almost N number of columns.

I tried using data columns and rows to display. And able to show the table. But since the table has many columns, I can see columns present beyond window width and window height. How can I add scroll mode for both horizontally and vertically so the user can scroll and view the table properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem，and i try this ,put the tabledata in the listview

```
import flet as ft

def main(page):
    table=ft.DataTable(
        border=ft.border.all(2, "red"),
        show_bottom_border=True,
        #columns 里必须添加 DataColumn 类型的控件
        columns=[
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("名字")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("电话")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("地址"), numeric=True),
            ],
        #rows 里必须添加 DataRow 类型的控件
        #DataRow 
        rows=[
            ft.DataRow(
                cells=[
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John")),
                    ])
            ]
        )
    lv = ft.ListView(expand=1, spacing=10, padding=20, auto_scroll=True)
    lv.controls.append(table)
    page.add(lv)
    def button_clicked(e):
        
        
        b=ft.DataRow(
                cells=[
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John")),
                    ])

        table.rows.append(b)
        page.update()
        print("按钮被点击")
    page.add(ft.ElevatedButton(text="添加一行数据",on_click=button_clicked,data=0))

ft.app(target=main)
```

Comment: How do you get it to scroll? It just goes off the screen and nothing I do makes it scroll

Answer (score 0):

Oh. @thw023824 Thanks, From Your snippet it is clearly understood that embedding datatable in other controls which have scroll property can help to enable scroll mode. I see listview can only help on horizontal scrolling. But I also have N number of columns. I tried below snippet to get my requirement.

```
import flet as ft
def main(page):
    table=ft.DataTable(
        border=ft.border.all(2, "red"),
        show_bottom_border=True,
        #columns 里必须添加 DataColumn 类型的控件
        columns=[
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("HELLO 1")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("BYE 2")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("SAMPLE COLUMN 3")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("DUMMY COLUMN 4")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("HELLO COLUMNS 5")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("BYE COLUMNS 6")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("OKAY COLUMNS 7")),ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("I LOVE COLUMNS 8")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("COLUMNS FOR SCROLLING 9"), numeric=True),
            ],
        #rows 里必须添加 DataRow 类型的控件
        #DataRow 
        rows=[
            ft.DataRow(
                cells=[
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 1")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 2")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 3")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 4")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 5")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 6")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 7")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 8")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 9")),
                    ])
            ]
        )
    cv = ft.Column([table],scroll=True)
    rv = ft.Row([cv],scroll=True,expand=1,vertical_alignment=ft.CrossAxisAlignment.START)
    page.add(rv)
    def button_clicked(e):
        b=ft.DataRow(
                cells=[  
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 1")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 2")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 3")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 4")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 5")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 6")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 7")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 8")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 9")),
                    ])

        table.rows.append(b)
        page.update()
        print("按钮被点击")
    add_row = ft.ElevatedButton(text="添加一行数据",on_click=button_clicked,data=0)
    page.add(add_row)

ft.app(target=main)
```

Answer (score -1):

write

rv = ft.Row([cv], scroll=ft.ScrollMode.ALWAYS,
expand=1,vertical_alignment=ft.CrossAxisAlignment.START)

this is working

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how your answer adds to the already-accepted answer?