# Flat Datatable with scroll mode in a responsive layout

Tags: python, flet

I would like to get a flat Datatable with scroll mode contained in the second column in a responsive layout. I tried to adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74896789/python-flet-scroll-mode-for-datatable) example without success.

Please find my code below.

```
import flet as ft
def main(page):
    table=ft.DataTable(
        border=ft.border.all(2, "red"),
        show_bottom_border=True,
        #columns 里必须添加 DataColumn 类型的控件
        columns=[
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("HELLO 1")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("BYE 2")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("SAMPLE COLUMN 3")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("DUMMY COLUMN 4")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("HELLO COLUMNS 5")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("BYE COLUMNS 6")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("OKAY COLUMNS 7")),ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("I LOVE COLUMNS 8")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("COLUMNS FOR SCROLLING 9"), numeric=True),
            ],
        #rows 里必须添加 DataRow 类型的控件
        #DataRow 
        rows=[
            ft.DataRow(
                cells=[
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 1")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 2")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 3")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 4")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 5")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 6")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 7")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 8")),
                    ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John 9")),
                    ])
            ]
        )
    cv = ft.Column([table],scroll=True)
    pick = ft.ElevatedButton("Pick files", icon=ft.icons.UPLOAD_FILE,
           on_click=lambda _: self.pick_files_dialog.pick_files(
               allow_multiple=False
           ))
    ##rv = ft.Row([cv],scroll=True,expand=1,vertical_alignment=ft.CrossAxisAlignment.START)
    rv = ft.ResponsiveRow([
        ft.Column(col={"sm": 2, "md": 3, "xl": 4}, controls=[pick]),
        ft.Column(col={"sm": 8, "md": 8, "xl": 8}, controls=[cv])
    ])    
    page.add(rv)


ft.app(target=main)
```